# Excel multiple IF AND

Tags: excel

I am struggling with an excel formula with multiple IF AND conditions. maybe you can help me. Here is an explanation of what I want to achieve:

List different prices if TWO conditions are met.

If A1=Ferrari AND B1=red, price=500; IF A1=Ferrari AND B1=gold, price=550; IF A1=Toyota AND B1=red, price=100, IF A1=Toyota and color=gold, price=110, else leave cell blank´

I hope you understand what I want to achieve and can help me.

This is what I tried but it gives me an error. I am using google sheets by the way.

```
=IF(AND(I27="ferrari"; K27="red")Variables!$R$1;IF(AND(I27="ferrari"; K27="gold")Variables!$R$2;IF(AND(I27="toyota"; K27="red")Variables!$V$3;IF(AND(I27="toyota"; K27="gold")Variables!$V$4;""))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got your semi colons and commas mixed up! Try this...

```
=IF(AND(I27="ferrari",K27="red"),Variables!$R$1,IF(AND(I27="ferrari",K27="gold"),Variables!$R$2,IF(AND(I27="toyota",K27="red"),Variables!$V$3,IF(AND(I27="toyota",K27="gold"),Variables!$V$4,""))))
```

You were also missing commas after some of your closing parentheses.

Comment: awesome, thank you so much. I got it to work. Had to change all commas to semi colons because its google sheets. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Glad it helped. Anyone having problems with commas and semicolons might like to take a look at this ... https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99938/google-sheets-documentation-falsely-using-commas-to-separate-parameters